# Why my gradient descent function to make polynomial equation for sinx can't work

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I need to code a programme to use gradient descend to fit polynomial equation to sin(x).And I am required to can't not use the autograd of pytorch,so I need to manipulate my myself.

I have check my code for many times,but I can't find problems.I think the process of gradient haven't problem.And I use a simple x,y to check the forward and backward in my code.The result of code is same with calculate in my paper.

However,the true is that the loss of model ascend gradually.Can somebody can help me?this is a homework of my teacher.Help!!Maybe the code is a bit long,I will sincerely appreciate you if you can have a look!

the code is as below:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset,DataLoader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##DataSet and DataLoader
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = torch.linspace(0,10,500)
        self.y = torch.sin(self.x)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.x[index],self.y[index])
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

dataset = MyDataset()
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=50,num_workers=0,shuffle=True)

##Model
class MyModel():
    def __init__(self,n):
        assert n>=1 
        self.n = n
        self.parameters = torch.randn((1,n+1)) #[1,n+1]，Θ0，Θ1...Θn
    
    def backward(self,weight,x):
        """
        weight : (batch,1) y_pred-y
        x : (batch,1)
        """
        x = x.expand(x.shape[0],self.n).clone() #size:(batch,1) -> (batch,n)
        x = torch.concat((torch.ones(x.shape[0],1),x),dim=1) #size:(batch,n) -> size:(batch,n+1)
        
        gradient_tensor = torch.zeros_like(self.parameters)
        for i in range(self.n+1):
            gradient_tensor[0,i] =  torch.mean(torch.pow(x[:,i],i).unsqueeze(-1) * weight,dim=0)
        return gradient_tensor
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x = x.expand(x.shape[0],self.n).clone() #size:(batch,1) -> (batch,n)
        x = torch.concat((torch.ones(x.shape[0],1),x),dim=1) #,size:(batch,n) -> (batch,n+!)
        for i in range(self.n + 1): 
            x[:,i] = torch.pow(x[:,i],i)
        return x @ self.parameters.T
    
    def step(self,gradient_tensor,lr):
        self.parameters = self.parameters - lr * gradient_tensor

    def __call__(self,x):
        return self.forward(x)

model = MyModel(5) #5 polinomial

##process of training
def train(model:MyModel,epoch=500,lr=1e-5,name=''):
    loss_list = []
    for i in range(epoch):
        total_loss = 0
        for x,y in dataloader:
            x,y = x.unsqueeze(-1),y.unsqueeze(-1) #size:(50) -> (50,1)
            y_pred = model(x)
            
            y_difference = (y_pred - y)
            loss = (0.5 * (y_difference ** 2)).mean()
            total_loss += loss
            
            gradient_tensor = model.backward(y_difference,x)
            model.step(gradient_tensor,lr)   
        print(f"epoch:{i}/{epoch} loss:{total_loss}")
        loss_list.append(total_loss)
    print(f"finish training model {name}")
    return loss_list

##train
loss_3 = train(model,name='3',epoch=10,lr=1e-8)
```

the validation of forward code(model is 5 polynomial):

```py
x = torch.tensor([0,torch.pi/2],dtype=torch.float64).unsqueeze(-1)
y = torch.tensor([0,1],dtype=torch.float64).unsqueeze(-1)
model.parameters = torch.tensor([1,1,1,1,1,1],dtype=torch.float64).unsqueeze(0)
y_pred = model(x)
y_pred

##output
#tensor([[ 1.0000],
#       [24.5652]])

temp = torch.pi/2
1 + temp + temp ** 2 + temp ** 3 + temp ** 4 + temp ** 5
##output:24.565165351269908
```

the validation of backward code:

```py
y_difference = y_pred - y
gradient_tensor = model.backward(y_difference,x)
gradient_tensor #output:tensor([[ 12.2826,  18.5080,  29.0724,  45.6668,  71.7332, 112.6782]])

weight = y_difference[1].item()
temp_gradient = torch.tensor([[1,0,0,0,0,0],
                              [weight * 1,weight * (torch.pi/2),weight * (torch.pi/2) ** 2,weight * (torch.pi/2) ** 3,weight * (torch.pi/2) ** 4,weight * (torch.pi/2) ** 5]],dtype=torch.float64)
print(temp_gradient.mean(dim=0)) #output:tensor([ 12.2826,  18.5080,  29.0724,  45.6668,  71.7332, 112.6782])
```

Comment: When I change the Dataset, create sinx of [-1,1]，I find it can gradient descent.When the Dataset is the sinx of [0,10],the loss is large,and I need to make the lr to nearly 1e-10 , the loss can slowly descent.But I can't still work well to the require of my teacher to make polynomial to fit sinx in [0,10].Can somebody have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PyTorch user, but I believe I can still provide some insights.

It seems when defining your model's parameters (I infer that these are weights), it seems they are of shape `(1,n+1)`, which I can safely assume that means 1 output node, `n` input nodes, and a bias, hence the `n+1`.

It looks to me this model only has zero hidden layers, as I can only see one parameter. Please do correct me if I am wrong, as this assumption constructs everything below.

When your model only has one layer, the model is unable to separate non-linear data. This is observed with the classic [XOR Problem](https://www.educative.io/answers/xor-problem-in-neural-network), faced by single-layer [Perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), or sometimes called or Rosenblatt Perceptrons.

We return to your problem. In your comment you left, you mentioned that the gradient descent works for `sin(x)` within [-1,1]. We notice that `sin(x)` somewhat resembles the line `y = x` as we zoom in on `x = 0`.

The scope of `sin(x)` within [-1,1] gives a graph that is easily linearly regressed to low loss. We can somewhat relate this to `y = x` approximating `sin(x)`.

However, when seeing what `sin(x)` within [0,10] looks like, we see a *wave*, and we cannot necessarily see any linear correlation between `x` and `sin(x)`. Therefore, as we can imagine, your network is approximating to the line `y = 0` to minimise the loss. And this is not a good approximation by any means, therefore a high loss value.

You would solve this by implementing another layer, turning your single-layer perceptron into a multi-layer perceptron. I would recommend going over [These Notes](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/varun.kanade/teaching/ML-MT2017/lectures/lecture14.pdf), as they cover the maths behind forward and back propagation pretty well. And they're regardless to how many layers you have, unlike [Wikipedia's Generalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Derivation), which may mislead you to apply a conditional statement in your code, when it is entirely not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But My model is a polynomial model,you can see in the 'forward ' function in my model,there is a code **x[:,i] = torch.pow(x[:,i],i)**.I consider that the model still has the ability to separate non-linear data.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what linear data/model means. `torch.pow` is still linear. Non-linear means the parameters are non-linear terms, not the data. `torch.pow` is still a linear term. this is why we need a hidden layer to separate non-linear data, since only then we have a non-linear model.